# Starter engaging, but engine won't turn over

Tags: starting

A quick synopsis of what has happened so far:

2011 Hyundai Santa Fe, 3.5L.  Was dealing with an intermittent click/no start issue for a few weeks.  When the issue would occur, I could get the car to start by either tapping on the starter with a long screwdriver, or by jumping the relay.

8 days ago, I returned home at around 10PM.  Went to start the car at about 8 the next morning, and the issue came up again.  Starter would engage, but nothing else.  Tapping/jumping the relay didn't help this time, so I figure the starter had finally died.  Replace the starter, and nothing is different.  I can hear the click of the starter engaging, but nothing else.

Just to eliminate possibilities, I replace the ignition switch.  Same issue. I get a new replacement starter, just in case this one is bad, and had them test it in the store, so starter is known good.

Starter is getting battery voltage on the larger wire with the key off, and a drop of about 0.6V when attempting to start.  Smaller wire, no voltage with key off and approximately the same reading as the large wire when attempting to start.  Vehicle behaves the same way whether in park or in neutral.  Jumping the starter relay changes nothing.  The engine ground on the passenger side and the chassis ground on the driver's fender are both good (sanded to bare metal and reattached).  Engine will turn with a breaker bar via the crankshaft pulley nut.  Battery is less than a year old and is showing 12.8V.

Is there an area I'm overlooking? Vehicle's OEM security? I'm at my wit's end with this.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you checked the battery to starter cable for breaks? Try connecting a jump lead directly from battery to starter...

Comment: Yes. The end of the starter cable is showing battery voltage with the key off, even while disconnected.

Comment: Add  a jump lead from the battery negative terminal to the engine and see if it then works.

Comment: what is the cranking voltage of battery?

Comment: Update on this....broken flywheel.